# Owl Carousel 2 beta , add "selected" class on Url Hash Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am trying to add "selected" class to the "url hash button".

Look at the original demo: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/urlhashnav.html

I want that `<a class="button secondary url" href="#zero">zero</a>` will change to `<a class="button secondary url selected" href="#zero">zero</a>` when clicking on it, or item autoplay on it, or drag/swipe item on it.

I tried for one button to test but it is not working:

HTML:

```
 <div id="owl-appt" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item one" data-hash="one"><img src="img/gallery/home/appt1/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="item two" data-hash="two"><img src="img/gallery/home/appt1/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="item three" data-hash="three"><img src="img/gallery/home/appt1/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>


      <a class="url one" href="#one"><img src="img/gallery/home/appt1/s1.jpg" /></a>
      <a class="url two" href="#two"><img src="img/gallery/home/appt1/s2.jpg" /></a>
      <a class="url three" href="#three"><img src="img/gallery/home/appt1/s3.jpg" /></a>
```

JS:

```
$("#owl-appt").owlCarousel(
          {
            items : 1,
            autoplay:false,           

            animateOut: 'fadeOut',
            loop:false,
            responsive: true,
            callbacks: true,
            URLhashListener:true,
            startPosition: '#one',

          });
if($("#owl-appt .item.one").parent().is(".active")){
  $("a.url.one").addClass("selected");
}else{
  $("a.url.one").removeClass("selected");
};
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but did you find the solution for this issue? I got the same issue but couldn't find the solution for it.

Answer (score -2):

I think if #owl-appt .item - active, you need to compare the contents of the data-hash = "#one" and a href = "#one" and if you are assigned to "selected" link. Sorry, I'm not a programmer, but only the HTML coder, but I was too interested in this question.